# Extract trend of time series with less than two periods

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I understand that a time series decomposition won't work if I have a univariate time series (daily frequency) with only one period (e.g., 1-Jan-2019 till 1-Aug-2020).

But won't it be possible to extract just the trend for such a series?

What are the methods that can help in this regard? and if the function exists within the R paradigm.

Thanks

Comment: If you can't order the values in time, which is what it means to not have more than one period, then the "trend" is really the mean.  You can mean-center it with ease.

Comment: @EngrStudent it is a time series data

Comment: If it is univariate time series, then you can order them, and you can know the distance between measurements.  In that case it is absolutely possible to detrend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply regress your time series on the dates. R will automatically convert your dates into a numerical object that counts days from some origin. The parameter estimate will then show the increment day-over-day.

If you want to detrend your series, simply take the residuals from this model. If you don't want to center the detrended series (i.e., don't want to also remove the overall level), then just add the estimated intercept back in.

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2020-08-01"),by="day")
set.seed(1)
foo <- ts(rnorm(length(dates)),start=dates[1])

plot(foo)
(model <- lm(foo~dates))
detrended <- ts(residuals(model),start=dates[1])
plot(detrended)
```

Comment: so, are you saying that the residuals are my trend component for the series?

Comment: No, the trend + level would be the fitted values from the model. The residuals would be the detrended and deleveled series.

Comment: sorry for my naivety, will I get the trend values if I subtract detrended from foo ?

Comment: Yes. Or, more easily, just take the fitted values from the model via `predict(model)` (which will include the trend and the intercept).